# Upgrading email template

Tags: managed-package, email, email-template, package, beta-managed-package

I have a package and make changes to an email template.

Obviously, if I uninstall previous versions of the package and install a new version the template everything will be hunky dory.  But, if I don't uninstall there are couple of permutations:

1. Managed version already installed - New Managed version installed over this
2. Managed version already installed - New Managed Beta version installed over this  (from my investigation the email template does not get updated.).
3. Managed Beta version already installed - New Managed version installed over this
4. Managed Beta version already installed - New Managed Beta version installed over this.

Is there ever a case when I don't need to do the uninstall and the deployed package will use latest template?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Email Templates are not upgradable, as per the documentation [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/packagingGuide/Content/packaging_packageable_components.htm). Instead you can consider using a **Visualforce Component** and **Visualforce Email Template**. You can put as little or as much content in the component that will be then referenced by the template. Visualforce Components are upgradable. Provide an attribute on your component to pass in the '**relatedTo**' property from the template.